# File not found, no such file or directory in GEE python

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-python-api, accuracy

I follow step by step in :
[https://geemap.org/notebooks/33_accuracy_assessment/#split-training-and-testing](https://geemap.org/notebooks/33_accuracy_assessment/#download-confusion-matrix)

When the step to download confusion matrix, there is error. I type the code :

```
import csv
import os

out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
training_csv = os.path.join(out_dir, 'train_accuracy.csv')
testing_csv = os.path.join(out_dir, 'test_accuracy.csv')

with open(training_csv, "w", newline="") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(train_accuracy.getInfo())

with open(testing_csv, "w", newline="") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(test_accuracy.getInfo())
```

Then the error is like this :

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-96b0f54cfa85> in <cell line: 8>()
     6 testing_csv = os.path.join(out_dir, 'test_accuracy.csv')
     7
----> 8 with open(training_csv, "w", newline="") as f:
     9     writer = csv.writer(f)
    10     writer.writerows(train_accuracy.getInfo())

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Downloads/train_accuracy.csv'
```

Then I go to the next step with no error. I curious, why the error happen? What is wrong?

Comment: Are you working with Windows or Linux?

Comment: I use MX Linux. But, I run using Colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Colab, it can use the current working directory rather than the root directory.

```
out_dir = os.getcwd()
testing_csv = os.path.join(out_dir, 'test_accuracy.csv')
```

This answer is from the author. Thank you for the author. The answer is in https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/issues/1670